# How to limit character input in UIAlertView UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertview

I am trying to limit the number of characters my user is allowed to input into my `UITextField` within my `UIAlertView`.

I've tried the some common answers on the web. Such as shown below :

```
  #define MAXLENGTH 10


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > MAXLENGTH) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:MAXLENGTH-1];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe this is allowed - referring too https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html `"The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified"`

Comment: Are you using a textfielddelegate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.h file

```
  @property (strong,nonatomic)  UITextField *alertText;

@interface LocationSearchViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)butPostalCode:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alrt.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[[alrt textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"Enter postal Code"];
alertText = [alrt textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
alertText.delegate=self;
alrt.tag=100;
[alrt show];
}



-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if(yourtextfieldname.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0) {
    return NO;

}
return YES;
}
```

**Swift**

```
class LocationSearchViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

 Var alertText:UITextField!
}

func butPostalCode(sender: AnyObject) {
var alrt: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "", message: "", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OK")
alrt.alertViewStyle = .PlainTextInput
alrt.textFieldAtIndex(0).placeholder = "Enter postal Code"
alertText = alrt.textFieldAtIndex(0)
alertText.keyboardType = .NumberPad
alertText.delegate = self
alrt.tag = 100
alrt.show()
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
if yourtextfieldname.text.length >= 10 && range.length == 0 {
    return false
}
return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't allowed. You aren't allowed to mess with a `UIAlertView`s hierarchy and so you can't go changing things on it like the `UITextField`s properties.

Please see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Specifically

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified

**EDIT**

Whilst you shouldn't be messing with the `UIAlertView` hierarchy itself like I have said above, you might actually be able to set the `UITextField`s delegate but first you need to retrieve it. First make sure you have set the `UITextFieldDelegate` in the header file (`.h` file).

Then after you have created your `UIAlertView` and set the [`alertViewStyle:` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW23), so we have something like

```
// We create an instance of our UIAlertView
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

// We set the alertViewStyle to a plain text input, so 1 textfield
[myAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

// Then we retrieve that UITextField from the index 0 
UITextField *plainTextField = [myAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
// Now that we have retrieved the text field we can set the delegate on it/
// Probably best to give it a tag as well so we can identify it later.
[plainTextField setDelegate:self]; 
[plainTextField setTag:1001];
```

Once we have set the delegate you should then enter your method as `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` is a `UITextFieldDelegate` method.

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Make sure that it is our textField that we are working on otherwise forget the whole thing.
    if([textField tag] == 1001) {
        if([textField text].length >= 10 && range.length == 0) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Warning**

As the text field being retrieved from `textFieldAtIndex:` is part of the `UIAlertView`s hierarchy Apple may class this as altering the `UIAlertView` which isn't allowed (See first part of answer) and whatever you do don't use `addSubview:` when using `UIAlertView`s

Comment: @rosshump please be aware that that piece of documentation has actually been changed since I wrote this though it still stands what I have said it has less documentation around the altering the `UIAlertView` hierarchy because you `UIAlertView` has been deprecated.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for letting me know! I haven't updated my apps for iOS 8 just yet, but I will make sure to read through the documentation and update them accordingly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#define MAXLENGTH 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *nextValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, string];
    if ([nextValue length] > MAXLENGTH) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                                              message:@"You can't insert more than 10 characters"                          
                                              delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil                          
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Close", nil];        
        [alert show];            
        return NO;            
    }
    return YES;
}
```