# UIAlertView with multiple text inputs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add new work order (TEST)" message:@"Please fill out all fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Add" otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *alertTextFieldName = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextFieldName.placeholder = @"Work order name";
alertTextFieldName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
UITextField *alertTextFieldProjectNo = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
alertTextFieldProjectNo.placeholder = @"ProjectNo";
alertTextFieldProjectNo.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
UITextField *alertTextFieldSubName = [alert textFieldAtIndex:2];
alertTextFieldSubName.placeholder = @"Sub account name";
alertTextFieldSubName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
[alert show];
```

Im trying to do this but I get error: NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Shouldn't I be able to add multiple textfields to the aletView? the -textFieldAtIndex: give me the notion that its possible. Am I wrong?

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281508/how-to-limit-character-input-in-uialertview-uitextfield/24281666#24281666) helps you

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. Better use UIAlertController.

Comment: I don't think that is possible to use more than 2 text field using UIAlertView, but from iOS8 you can use UIAlertViewController that can accept more than 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code for Add mulitple textfield in `UIAlertView`

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 100)];

UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,252,25)];
textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField1.placeholder = @"Username";
textField1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField1.delegate = self;
[v addSubview:textField1];

UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,30,252,25)];
textField2.placeholder = @"Password";
textField2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField2.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField2.delegate = self;
[v addSubview:textField2];


UITextField *textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,60,252,25)];
textField3.placeholder = @"Address";
textField3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField3.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField3.delegate = self;
[v addSubview:textField3];


UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
[av setValue:v  forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[av show];
```

I hope this code useful for you.

Comment: Im not sure why someone down voted your answer without making a comment with some elaboration on what would be a better solution. Meanwhile, should I make the textfields as properties if I want to retrieve their values from the uialertview delegate method clickedButtonAtIndex:  ?

Comment: yes that's possible . you want to create your 3 textfield global variable and then u will able to get value from textfield .

Comment: how to get this action ? clickbutton at index, or dissmiss is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886048/ios-multiple-text-fields-on-a-uialertview-in-ios-7) will be quite useful.
If you need just two fields, then go ahead with **UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput**. 
Otherwise, provide your own subview with everything required for your logic.

P.S. **textFieldAtIndex** method can be used to receive already existing text fields, but you're trying to receive fields that don't exist yet.

Comment: im not sure how textFieldAtIndex is supposed to work then, since textFieldatIndex: 0 refers to the alert textfield. How would i get one at index:1 then? seems tome it would be form alert view

Comment: @DevilInDisguise yes, of course it should return text field from UIAlertView. I'm not sure, but I think the text fields, that can be returned by this method are created by _UIAlertView itself_, but you can control these fields using _UIAlertViewStyle_. As we can see from styles enumeration, there's not much options. There is already another answer, using _accessoryView_ key, I think you should try it. In fact, it's equal to adding your own subview.